# Different output printing stdout on console/redirecting to a file

Tags: c++, bash, math, g++, stdout

I have a problem with stdout on bash. 
First, I have a program named **Channel_Flow** which is written by C++ language. This program basically compute some maths on computational fluid dynamics field.

My problem occur when I use this:
`$ ./Channel_Flow`
for my program.

The output is different when I redirect the output, like:
`$ ./Channel_Flow > result.dat`

The difference is really significant, some maths is computed and behave differently. I never have this kind of error before.
Is there anything wrong with the way I execute the program? Anyone has a hint for this?

Thank you. If I need to add some details, I'll gladly edit the question.
(For additional information, I use makefile to compile the file with --c++11 flags and -O2 optimization flags with g++ 5.3.1 compiler)

**edit**
I add some of the outputs from the latter command:
`substep - 1
1 1 10 : -18693.7
2 1 10 : -18693.7
3 1 10 : -18693.7
4 1 10 : -18693.7
5 1 10 : -18693.7
6 1 10 : -18693.7
7 1 10 : -18693.7
8 1 10 : -18693.7
9 1 10 : -18693.7`

From the first commmand, I got this:

`substep - 1
1 1 10 : 3.47858
2 1 10 : 3.47858
3 1 10 : 3.47858
4 1 10 : 3.47858
5 1 10 : 3.47858
6 1 10 : 3.47858
7 1 10 : 3.47858
8 1 10 : 3.47858
9 1 10 : 3.47858`

The code is complex so I'm still searching where the source of the problem is. What I'm asking here why my output has a different result when I write it to a file?
The correct one is the console output.

I tried this: (As the first answer suggests).

```
# have a specific error file
./Channel_Flow > result.dat 2>errors.log
#or all to the same:
./Channel_Flow > result.dat 2>&1
```

but the file errors.log is empty. The second command gave the exact same result.
**EDIT AGAIN**

I use an offstream to print my result,

```
std::ofstream testing("testing.dat");
if (k==0)  {
  testing  <<  i << " " << j << " " << k << " : " << ux[i][j][k] << std::endl;  
  std::cout  <<  i << " " << j << " " << k << " : " << ux[i][j][k] << std::endl;  
}
```

I use the first command:

```
$ ./Channel_Flow
```

Output:
`substep - 1
1 1 10 : -18693.7
2 1 10 : -18693.7
3 1 10 : -18693.7
4 1 10 : -18693.7
5 1 10 : -18693.7
6 1 10 : -18693.7
7 1 10 : -18693.7
8 1 10 : -18693.7
9 1 10 : -18693.7`

(On both ofstream file (testing.dat) and the console interface)
I use the second command:

```
$ ./Channel_Flow > result.dat
```

Output:
`substep - 1
1 1 10 : 3.47858
2 1 10 : 3.47858
3 1 10 : 3.47858
4 1 10 : 3.47858
5 1 10 : 3.47858
6 1 10 : 3.47858
7 1 10 : 3.47858
8 1 10 : 3.47858
9 1 10 : 3.47858`

(On both ofstream file (testing.dat) and the console interface)

Comment: *You should really include some code* in your problem, at least a workable snippet where you think the problem is. You could try redirecting to a .txt file instead, just to see how the output changes and make it readable. (Not that I think that's the problem, just a suggestion, and potentially useful experiment.)

Comment: Do you check for errors from your input operations?  Have you printed the input values for comparison?  Can you show what you get in the two cases?  Have you tried reducing the code to make an MCVE ([MCVE]) which still demonstrates the problem?  Where does the input data come from?  The two ways you show of running the program should be fine.  If you were redirecting standard error too, you could easily get different results between the two. Are you using `fork()` anywhere in the code, or multiple threads?

Comment: You're going to have to provide more details, because I'm having a hard time imagining a scenario where this is even possible. The only thing that comes to mind is uninitialized variables, but that should give you inconsistent results no matter where the output is going.

Comment: @NonCreature0714 I've tried that, but it still persist. Perhaps you can take a look on my edited question.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I've add some outputs on the question. I did print ./Channel_Flow > result.dat 2>errors.log, but errors.log is empty. I don't really know what causing it, I'm still searching.

Comment: @MarkRansom I've added some details, Is that enough? I can't really update it with my code since I'm still searching where the problem started.

Comment: @J.Chomel I've added some details, perhaps you can take a look.

Comment: I've added another details.

Comment: @v8areu, thanks, but now it is beyond my understanding :)  Maybe try this: `./Channel_Flow | tee  result.dat `. Do you still get difference between both?

Comment: @v8areu, this also could be the typing of the values of your matrix. When outputing to console, it is some kind of signed float, and an unsigned type to file. Try changing the type maybe.

Comment: I can't immediately think what would cause the behaviour you're seeing.  Have you got [`valgrind`](http://vagrant.org/) available?  If so, use it.  The apparent consistency of the alternative outputs is surprising.  Without more code, I don't think we're going to be able to help.  You need to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  You must affirm that you've printed out the data after it is read (before any further processing) and that the results are the same.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably because you have things going to `stdout` and other going to `stderr`, and you redirect both differently.

- [stdout](/questions/tagged/stdout) - i.e. Standard output are normal things coming from the program.
- [stderr](/questions/tagged/stderr) - i.e. Error output, I let you guess.

So in your case, with `./Channel_Flow > result.dat` you only redirect `stdout` to `result.dat`, leaving `stderr` display in the console.

If you want every thing to go to files:

```
# have a specific error file
./Channel_Flow > result.dat 2>errors.log
#or all to the same:
./Channel_Flow > result.dat 2>&1
```

### edit

See what happens in your case with

```
## and this latest would both log to console and write to file:
./Channel_Flow |tee result.dat
```

Comment: errors.log is empty, the second command still gives me the exact same result.

Comment: OK, sorry couldn't help you. thank you for adding the details we needed.